# Cursor to remain pointer in area

Tags: html, css

I'm building a little hidden object game. I can't seem to stop the cursor from turning into a hand (on chrome anyway) which pretty much defeats the purpose of the objects being hidden. I've read a lot of stackexchange posts on this but none work for me. Below is one of the maps and few things I have tried, some inline, some CSS.

I also have an issue with blue outline when I click one of the polygons, but should probably make that a separate question. Please assist.

This is the actual game page- 
[Game page](http://bickersc.com/free/game/game.html)

```
    <map name="m__r3_c7" id="m__r3_c7">
<area shape="poly" coords="28,91,52,93,70,89,71,74,82,67,80,52,70,40,55,28,47,30,29,31,20,21,5,9,-6,0,-27,10,-10,19,-18,20,-9,44,2,61,3,68,20,73,29,76" style="cursor:default" href="javascript:;" alt="" onclick="MM_nbGroup('down','navbar10','n_r3_c6','images/_r3_c6_s4.jpg','n_r3_c7','images/_r3_c7_s4.jpg',1);"  />
</map>
```

I've tried

```
area {
cursor: default; 
display:block;
}

javascript:void(0);

javascript:void(null)

style="cursor:default"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's coming from the `href="javascript:;`. Just remove that from your `<area>` elements and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the outline from polygons you need to add in css : `outline :0;`

example :

```
area, area:focus {
outline: 0;
}
```